# hibernate can't detect named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to execute a hibernate query. After I created the query, "query.getQueryString()"
prints like below:

```
select a 
from com.mycompany.model.dwh.Instruction a 
where a.custBillAcctId = :accountId
```

Then when I am trying to set parameter:

```
query.setParameter("accountId", new BigDecimal(accountId));
```

I get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: 
could not locate named parameter [accountId]
```

I print "query.getNamedParameters()", it seems empty. Hibernate somewhat can't detect :accountId. I tried different things, setting by parameter index, etc. All failed.
I did it millions of times in JEE-Hibernate, but I failed with Spring-Hibernate.

Environment:  Eclipse-Jetty
hibernate: 4.1.9.Final
springframework: 3.2.1.RELEASE

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TALIMAT")
public class Instruction implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "TALIMAT_ID")
@GenericGenerator(name="kaugen" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="kaugen")
private Long key;

@Id
@Column(name = "CUST_BILL_ACCT_ID")
private BigDecimal custBillAcctId;

....

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "INSERT_DATE")
private Date insertDate;
```

Here is my code:

```
    try {
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

         Query query = session.createQuery("select a from " +   
                               Instruction.class.getName() + " a 
                               where a.custBillAcctId = :accountId ");  


         System.out.println("getNamedParameters: ");
         for(String g:query.getNamedParameters()){
             System.out.println(g + "\n");
         }

         query.setParameter("accountId", new BigDecimal(accountId));

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code. From the query creation to its execution.

Comment: have a look at these [Similar1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433499/org-hibernate-queryparameterexception-could-not-locate-named-parameter) [Similar2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680813/org-hibernate-queryparameterexception-could-not-locate-named-parameter-userid)

Comment: @ Anirtak Varma I tried "similar1" but error did not change

Comment: 2 suggestions: write classname yourself, and try ussing ordinal parameter, just to see what happens. "select a from Instruction a where a.custBillAcctId = ?1". then set parameter as query.setParameter(1, new BigDecimal(accountId));

Comment: @Damian Both of them did not work. So I gave up and I just removed :accountId and used string concat for placing value. I know it is not good but, saved some time. thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the problem. It was a silly side-effect problem. I have multiple databaseContext.xml files each containing a datasources definition for a different database which application use. Although they are in seperate files, datasource id's were coinciding, this resulted in ambiguous behaviour.

When I gave them unique names, problem disappeared